# Check if a user is in the db

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have those methods

```
 public void insert(ContentValues values){
    try {
        database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        database.insertOrThrow(dbhelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        //releasing the resources.
        database.close();
        dbhelper.close();
    }
}
public Cursor query(){
    database=dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur=database.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    return cur;

}
```

One inserts data, and another queries data from my db.

Now I insert some data in the db

```
   values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("email",email);
                values.put("pass",password);
                values.put("contact",contact);

                DetailsDb detailsDb = new DetailsDb(this);
                Cursor cursor = detailsDb.query();

                if(cursor.getCount() > 0){

                    Toast.makeText(this,"Ooops user exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{

                    detailsDb.insert(values);
                    Toast.makeText(this,"You are registered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Basically, I am saying. If there is a row in the db (cursor.getCount > 0) then the user exists. If not then insert the new user. But if I enter the same user again then, I am getting the " You are registered" message. So something is wrong there. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: because the query function did't check if the data is exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rejecting a user if **any** user exists.

If you want to only reject an already existing user and thus allow multiple users then you need to check if that specific user exists.

So :-

Add a new method :-

```
public Cursor getUser(String email){
    database=dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String whereclause = "email=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{email};
    Cursor cur=database.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, whereclause, whereargs, null, null, null);
    return cur;
}
```

this equates to `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE email = the_email_to_check;` as opposed to `SELECT * FROM your_table;`

Then use :-

```
values = new ContentValues();
values.put("email",email);
values.put("pass",password);
values.put("contact",contact);

DetailsDb detailsDb = new DetailsDb(this);
Cursor cursor = detailsDb.getUser(email); //<<<<<<

if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Ooops user exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    if (detailsDb.insert(values) > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"You are registered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Attempt to register unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

- Note there is an additional check to see if the insert actually inserted the row (the  `insert` method returns the rowid of the inserted row which would be 1 or greater if the row was inserted, otherwise it returns -1).